# how to execute a script in every window that gets loaded in puppeteer?

Tags: puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I need to execute a script in every Window object created in Chrome – that is:

- tabs opened through puppeteer
- links opened by click()ing links in puppeteer
- all the popups (e.g. window.open or "_blank")
- all the iframes contained in the above

it must be executed without me evaluating it explicitly for that particular `Window` object...

I checked Chrome's documentation and what I should be using is `Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument`.
However, it doesn't look to be possible to use through puppeteer.

Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This searches for a target in all browser contexts.

An example of finding a target for a page opened

via `window.open()` or popups:

```
await page.evaluate(() => window.open('https://www.example.com/'))
const newWindowTarget = await browser.waitForTarget(async target => {

    await page.evaluate(() => {
        runTheScriptYouLike()
        console.log('Hello StackOverflow!')
    })

})
```

via `browser.pages()` or tabs

This script run evaluation of a script in the second tab:

```
const pageTab2 = (await browser.pages())[1]
const runScriptOnTab2 = await pageTab2.evaluate(() => {
    runTheScriptYouLike()
    console.log('Hello StackOverflow!')
})
```

via `page.frames()` or iframes

An example of getting eval from an iframe element:

```
const frame = page.frames().find(frame => frame.name() === 'myframe')
const result = await frame.evaluate(() => {
    return Promise.resolve(8 * 7);
});
console.log(result); // prints "56"
```

Hope this may help you